# How can I make the ast module of Python work in flask?

Tags: python

I have a python script which is using `ast.literal_eval` and is working fine.

```
import csv
import datetime
import time
import ast

def checkDateTime():
    fileName = "Bhuvneshwar Kumar-2018-05-10.csv"
    mydict = {}
    myList = []
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-05-10 14:41:38", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    period = 5
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as csv_reader:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_reader)
        print "Reading"
        for row in reader:
            currDict = ast.literal_eval(row[0])
            now = datetime.datetime.strptime(currDict["timeStamp"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            if((now >= start) and (now - start <= datetime.timedelta(minutes = 100))):
                myList.append(currDict)
                print currDict["timeStamp"]

checkDateTime()
```

However, the same method when used in Flask is throwing error:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import os
import csv
import datetime
import time
from testDict import entityDict, date
import json
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.route("/")

def helloFromBubble():
    return "Hi there!"

@app.route("/tweetsAllReq")
def stream():
    fileName = "#DDvSRH-2018-05-10-Watson.csv"
    csv_reader = csv.reader(FileTailer(open(fileName)))
    def generate():
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield '{}\n'.format(json.dumps(row))
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

@app.route("/tweetsTimeFrame", methods = ["GET"])
def streamEntity():
  tweetList = []
  entity = request.args.get("entity")
  startTime = request.args.get("start")
  period = request.args.get("period")
  if(period == None or startTime == None or entity == None):
    return "Status: Failure. Reason: Failed to load because of some missing params."
  fileName = str(entity) + "-" + str(date) + ".csv"
  start = datetime.datetime.strptime(startTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  with open(fileName, 'rb') as csv_reader:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_reader)
    for row in csv_reader:
      print(row)
      #currDict = ast.literal_eval(row[0])
      #now = datetime.datetime.strptime(currDict["timeStamp"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      #if((now >= start) and (now - start <= datetime.timedelta(seconds = period))):
        #tweetList.append(currDict)
  return "hi"

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

While printing in the file, it is showing the first row(from my csv) very well.
The EOL is occurring at `\n` and I do know how to escape it without modifying my CSV file. My issue is to make the flask script working as good as my another script(aforementioned).

This is the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997,
>   in **call** return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in
>   wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in
>   handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in
>   wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in
>   full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in
>   handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in
>   full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in
>   dispatch_request return
>   self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
>   "/home/aviral/dev/bubble/apiV2.py", line 45, in streamEntity currDict
>   = ast.literal_eval(row[0]) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse return
>   compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line
>   1
>       "
>       ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

The contents of the csv file(few lines):

> "{u'emotion': {u'anger': 0.173654, u'joy': 0.167818, u'sadness':
>   0.275962, u'fear': 0.127876, u'disgust': 0.125381}, u'count': 1, u'sentiment': {u'score': 0.515437, u'label': u'positive'}, u'text':
>   u'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', u'disambiguation': {u'subtype': [], u'name':
>   u'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', u'dbpedia_resource':
>   u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bhuvneshwar_Kumar'}, 'tweetId':
>   '994588277943365633', 'timeStamp': '2018-05-10 14:41:38',
>   u'relevance': 0.710619, u'type': u'Person', 'tweet': 'FOUR\n\nJason
>   Roy drives it past Bhuvneshwar Kumar straight for the boundary.
>   \n\n#IPL2018 #DDvSRH'}"
>
> "{u'emotion': {u'anger': 0.173654, u'joy':
>   0.167818, u'sadness': 0.275962, u'fear': 0.127876, u'disgust': 0.125381}, u'count': 1, u'sentiment': {u'score': 0.515437, u'label': u'positive'}, u'text': u'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', u'disambiguation':
>   {u'subtype': [], u'name': u'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', u'dbpedia_resource':
>   u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bhuvneshwar_Kumar'}, 'tweetId':
>   '994588917839036422', 'timeStamp': '2018-05-10 14:44:11',
>   u'relevance': 0.710619, u'type': u'Person', 'tweet': 'FOUR\n\nJason
>   Roy drives it past Bhuvneshwar Kumar straight for the boundary.
>   \n\n#IPL2018 #DDvSRH'}"

Comment: That is a csv file with csv content!

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in csv_reader:
```

should be changed to

```
for row in reader:
```

The error was backslash n in the read rows. If they are read as a row, problem would have been solved. To ensure that the read thing is rows and not just a string, it is import to iterate in reader and not the file object: csv_reader.

The complete working code would then be:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys


from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import os
import csv
import datetime
import time
from testDict import entityDict, date
import json
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.route("/")

def helloFromBubble():
    return "Hi there!"

@app.route("/tweetsAllReq")
def stream():
    fileName = "#DDvSRH-2018-05-10-Watson.csv"
    csv_reader = csv.reader(FileTailer(open(fileName)))
    def generate():
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield '{}\n'.format(json.dumps(row))
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')

@app.route("/tweetsTimeFrame", methods = ["GET"])
def streamEntity():
  tweetList = []
  currDict = None
  entity = request.args.get("entity")
  startTime = request.args.get("startTime")
  period = int(request.args.get("period"))
  empty = []
  if(period == None):
    empty.append("period")
  if(startTime == None):
    empty.append("start")
  if(entity == None):
    empty.append(entity)
  if(len(empty) > 0):
    return "Status: Failure. Reason: Failed to load " + str(empty)
  fileName = str(entity) + "-" + str(date) + ".csv"
  start = datetime.datetime.strptime(startTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  with open(fileName, 'rb') as csv_reader:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_reader)
    for row in reader:
      currDict = ast.literal_eval(row[0])
      now = datetime.datetime.strptime(currDict["timeStamp"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      if((now >= start) and (now - start <= datetime.timedelta(minutes = period))):
        tweetList.append(currDict)
  return json.dumps(tweetList)

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```